# If $A, B$ are two open sets in $\mathbb R$ such that $A\cap B $ is compact, then show ....

Tags: compactness

If $A, B$ are two open sets in $\mathbb R$ such that  $A\cap B$ is compact, then show that $A\cap B =\varnothing$.

Since A is open then int$(A)\subseteq A$,  and same thing for $B$,  but I can't solve this.

Comment: What is $\phi$ in this context?

Comment: @mathisfun probably $\emptyset$

Comment: @supinf Thanks, it makes sense now. I edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**:

Keep in mind that the intersection of open sets is open again.
Do you know any set that is both open and compact?

Comment: yes i know ...(0,1)